# php pdf file uploading not working

Tags: php, pdf, file-upload, codeigniter-2, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to upload pdf file using codeigniter with multiple file upload extension,after allowing all different file types the issue exist with only pdf files,those are not recognized properly.
What i found in my POST variable using firebug for all pdf file was :

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadfile[]"; filename="abc.pdf"  
Content-Type: /instance/stamper/pickup/53e23aa5e8392f5ad816f2af081ec766:
```

Now i am not able to understand why file content type is going that way,also this is hosted on cpanel.
My controller code

```
$this->load->library('upload');  
        // Define file rules
        $this->upload->initialize(array(
            "upload_path"       =>  $path,
            "allowed_types"     =>  "gif|jpg|png|pdf|csv|doc|docx",
            "max_size"          =>  '2000',
            "max_width"         =>  '2000',
            "max_height"        =>  '2000'
        ));

        if($this->upload->do_multi_upload("uploadfile")){ echo "success"; }
```

MY HTML Form code

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" id="create_profile_form" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo site_url("/profile/create_profile"); ?>">
  <input type="file" id="bvn_certi_upload_name" name="uploadfile[]">
   <input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Upload" class = "btn btn-primary" />
  </form>
```

Form is submitted via ajax using jquery.form script.

Kindly advice